# Issues converting data from sqlite3 to csv, xml using python3

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, csv, xml.etree

***Note - this is for an assignment, rather than providing a solution, if you could point me to where I'm messing up my code, that would be much appreciated.**

I am writing a small program that interacts with an sqlite3 table, an XML file, and a csv file. When a user runs the program for the first time, I am checking for each of those files in the app's directory and then creating them / populating them with data.

What's supposed to happen (when no file is present in the directory):
1. Create a table (payrate.db)
2. Insert values into the table
3. Using the data from the table, insert the same values into an XML file (payrate.xml)
4. Again, using the data from the table, insert the same values into a CSV file (payrate.csv)

What's happening:
1. All three files are created
2. The XML file contains only the 'root' value specified in my program
3. The CSV file is completely empty
4. No errors are returned by the program. The tkinter GUI loads and displays just fine

I've tried searching on this, and I've seen similar errors, but none of the solutions I found have resolved the issues I'm seeing. Any guidance on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

My guess is that somehow my connection is closing before the 'rows' list can be populated, and that's resulting in empty data. I'm just not sure how to resolve this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env/python3
import csv
import os
import os.path as op
import sqlite3 as sq
from contextlib import closing
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def checkDir(self):
    directory = op.dirname(op.abspath(__file__))
    path = op.join(directory, 'payrate.db') # Path of payrate.db
    DB_LOC = op.join(directory, 'payrate.db')
    conn = sq.connect(DB_LOC) # Create connection object
    c = conn.cursor() # Get a cursor object
    if os.path.exists(path) == False:
        # Database does not exist
        self.err['text'] = "Data not found. Creating the database..."
        # Payrate table string
        tableString = """Create Table payrate(
                        ID INTEGER not null primary key,
                        FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(30),
                        LAST_NAME VARCHAR(30),
                        PAYRATE DECIMAL(99999, 2)"""

        c.execute(tableString) # Create a table

        ## Insert rows of data into the table
        c.execute("INSERT INTO PAYRATE VALUES(0,'John', 'Nolan', 99999.99)")
        c.execute("INSERT INTO PAYRATE VALUES(1,'Jane', 'Doe', 99999.99)")
        c.execute("INSERT INTO PAYRATE VALUES(2,'Tom', 'McCune', 99999.99)")
        c.execute("INSERT INTO PAYRATE VALUES(3,'Tim', 'Guerin', 99999.99)")
        c.execute("INSERT INTO PAYRATE VALUES(4,'Sally', 'Pleas', 99999.99)")
        c.execute("INSERT INTO PAYRATE VALUES(5,'Miranda', 'Conrad', 99999.99)")
        self.err['text'] = "Database created successfully. Checking for XML..."
    # Database already existed 
    else:
        self.err['text'] = "Database loaded successfully. Checking for XML file..."

    # set a variable with the database contents for reuse
    rows = list(c.fetchall())

    # change path to the xml document and check for existence
    path = op.join(directory, 'payrate.xml')
    if os.path.exists(path) == False:
        # database created, copy data to xml
        self.err['text'] = "Data not found. Creating the XML file..."
        # select all data from the database
        root = et.Element('Payrates')
        root.set('version', '1.0')
        et.ElementTree(root).write('payrate.xml')
        for row in rows:
            employee = et.SubElement(root, 'Employee',
            {
                'ID':row['ID'],
                'FirstName':row['FIRST_NAME'],
                'LastName':row['LAST_NAME'],
                'PayRate':row['PAYRATE'],
            })
            et.ElementTree(employee).write('payrate.xml')

        self.err['text'] = "XML file created successfully. Checking for CSV..."
    # XML file already existed
    else:
        self.err['text'] = "XML file loaded successfully. Checking for CSV file"

    # update path and check for CSV file
    path = op.join(directory, 'payrate.csv')
    if os.path.exists(path) == False:
        # database/xml created, copy data to csv
        self.err['text'] = "Data not found. Generating the CSV file..."
        # Add a row in the csv file for each line in the database
        with open(path, "w", newline='') as csvfile:
            for row in rows:
                filewriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
                filewriter.writerow(row)
        self.err['text'] = "Data created successfully. We're set to go!"
    # CSV file already existed
    else:
        self.err['text'] = "All data loaded successfully. Please enter values and choose your option."

    # save results and close the database connection
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this with help from a colleague.

Issue: I was opening the connection to 'payrate.db' before the program logic led to a missing file. What this was doing was causing an empty table to be created, and a subsequent empty .csv and .xml file.

In addition, I did not assign a query to my fetchall statement, and it was failing.